# How to avoid splitting of table at page end in Apache fop

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to create a PDF using Apache FOP.
I have a section of input which repeats as many number of times. With each section i have a table created in the page. After about 3 tables, there is a page break and the table is split into the current and the next page. I would want to avoid this and have the entire table in the next page.
Could you please guide as i am very new to Apache FOP.

XML section that contributes for table :

```
<SummaryDetails> 
<SummaryDetail>
<MediaType>P</MediaType>
<T1>
<T1ID>I</T1ID>
<T2>
<T2ID>T2</T2ID>
 <T3>
 <T3ID>T3</T3ID>
 </T3>
 </T2>
 /T1>
 </SummaryDetail>
 </SummaryDetails>
```

Code snippet:

The table consists of nested loop for T1, T2 and T3 sections in the xml. The table appears ok until it encounters a page break.

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-first" force-page-count="no-force" id="end">

<!--Header of table which appears in all pages-->
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
<fo:table >
<fo:table-column column-width="5.8cm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="8.1cm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="4.8cm"/>
<fo:table-body>
<fo:table-row height="3.1cm">
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</fo:static-content>

<!--Body of table-->
<fo:flow flow-name="body">
<!--This table appears only when the number of SummaryDetails section is greater than 1 and 
appears just once-->
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="count(./SummaryDetails) &gt; 1">
<fo:table margin-left="0.2cm"  >
<fo:table-body>
<fo:table-row>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

<!--This is the table which is having the issue-->
<fo:table>
<fo:table-body>
<xsl:for-each select="SummaryDetails">
<fo:table-row >
</fo:table-row>

<xsl:for-each select="SummaryDetail/T1">
<fo:table-row >
</fo:table-row>
<xsl:for-each select="T2">
<fo:table-row >
</fo:table-row>
<xsl:for-each select="T3">       
<fo:table-row >
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
<fo:table-row >
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
<fo:table-row>
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
<fo:table-row>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

The input xml is also explained here : [How to insert a new page when a table inside a for each block overflows from the current page sequence in Apache fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73151362/how-to-insert-a-new-page-when-a-table-inside-a-for-each-block-overflows-from-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using keep-with-next.within-page="always" in every row of the table and keep-with-next.within-page="always" on the 1st table cell and it worked out wonders. :)

```
<!--This is the table which is having the issue-->
<fo:table>
<fo:table-body>
<xsl:for-each select="SummaryDetails">
<fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
<fo:table-cell keep-with-next.within-page="always"></fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>

<xsl:for-each select="SummaryDetail/T1">
<fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
<fo:table-cell keep-with-next.within-page="always"></fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<xsl:for-each select="T2">
<fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
</fo:table-row>
<xsl:for-each select="T3">       
<fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
<fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
<fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
<fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always">
</fo:table-row >
</xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<fo:table keep-together.within-page="always">`.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#keep-together. The FOP compliance page states that FOP has limited support for `keep-together` (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-keep-together), but I would expect it to work on tables.

Comment: I tried this and i encountered 2 issues.
(1).  Page -2 left blank after the table which appears on condition SummaryDetails > 1
(2).  In page 3, table is incomplete and no new page is added. This makes the entire pdf incomplete.

Comment: You could try using an integer value for `keep-together.within-page`, but the FOP compliance page says that FOP has limited support for integer keeps (unlike some other formatters).

Comment: When you run up against the limits of Apache FOP, consider commercial alternatives such as [AH Formatter](https://www.antennahouse.com/formatter-v7?hsLang=en) or [XEP](https://www.renderx.com/tools/xep.html).

Comment: Hi Thanks :) using an integer avoided the issue (2) i.e incomplete page.
I tried using keep-with-next.within-page="always" in every row of the table and keep-with-next.within-page="always" on the 1st table cell and it worked out wonders. :)